# Vaadin ApexChartWrapper get dataURI() always null

Tags: apexcharts, vaadin24

ApexchartWrapper from Vaadin directory works like a charm but I need to put the generated chart into a pdf.

But I did not get it running so far.

if I do

```
chart.dataURI().then(t -> {
    System.out.println("return" + t.asString());
});
```

This is executed after the chart is already shown on the UI.

The question is how to get the dataURI of the chart.